# VScode "iostream" file not found in .h file while it's ok in .cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I'm writing a header file, the editor can't find `<iostream>`. And the `std` namespace can't be detected as well.

[image]

num.h

```cpp
#include "tag.h"
#include "token.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#ifndef NUM_H_
#define NUM_H_

class Num : public Token {
public:
  int value;
  Num(int v) : Token(Tag::NUM) { value = v; };
  std::string toString() {return " "+std::to_string(value);}
};


#endif
```

But the strange thing is, when I create a file that includes this header file, and write some demo code to test if this header file really works, then it works fine.

num.cpp

```cpp
#include "num.h"
int main() {
  Num n(1);
  std::string a = n.toString();
  std::cout<<a;
}
```

Here is what I get after running it:

[image]

I also find that it's fine to write `#include <iostream>` in the `.cpp` file, there won't be any error.

It's quite strange, I don't know what's wrong. Maybe it's a bug in VScode?

Comment: No need for `#include <stdio.h>` you have C++ version of it `#include <iostream>

Comment: Are you trying to compile your `.h` file?

Comment: @KPCT How to compile my .h file?  Can you show me the code using clang?

Comment: @KPCT I write ```include <stdio.h>``` to see if it can be found by vscode. It seems fine. Any C version header file can be found in my .h file.

Comment: I think I see your problem, but I am not familiar w it to say 100%, `-static-libgcc` is c library. Try replacing it with `-static-libstdc++`

Comment: What OS are you compiling this w? If it is Windows, -static-libgcc does not exist on windows